# Access the Data From The Generic Collection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, collections

I am Accessing the Data From the Database in the format like::

```
var dossiers = db.DossierHeaders.Where(x => x.CompanyID == SelectedCompany.Take(15).ToDataSourceResult(request);
```

This is accessed for filling the Data into Kendo Grid. That is why I need to used `.ToDatasource()`

I am getting the Data into dossiers but can't able to Access it in ::

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dossiers.Total; i++)
            {
                var testData = dossiers.Data[i];
            }
```

Please help me on this that How can I access the Data.  Because in dossiers there is Data & into that there are multiple values accessed from Databse like ::

```
dossier.Data=> Contains List of Data accessed from  Database
```

Means, I am getting Something like this.
[image: These fields are in dossier which is accessed from Database as shoown above]

[image: These Are the Datacontents Present in dossier.Data]

Comment: Did you tried reflection to access the properties/values? Its a master solution that works in scenarios like this.

Comment: Can't you just cast the Data back to IEnumerable<DossierHeader>() ?

Comment: How to Cast Back in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try using foreach...

```
foreach(DossierHeaders dh in dossiers.Data.Cast<DossierHeader>())
{
    var testData = dh.CompanyID;
}
```